# Mandrill Inbound Email routing

Tags: mandrill

having a bit of a conceptual issue here:

Using mandrill for sending email - ok. 
Configured mandrill for receiving email. the documentation states that incoming messages are posted to an URL. This means that such a page should exist and parse the messages.

Ideally incoming messages should end in my inbox. how can this be accomplished?

Do i have to make changes at the DNS level to route inbound email to my SMTP mail server?

Comment: try mailgun
http://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#routes
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703446/how-to-receive-the-emails-using-mailgun-in-node-js

Answer (score 7):

Mandrill's incoming features are completely optional.

Unless your application needs to programmatically process incoming mail (e.g. post-by-email for a blogging platform), *and* you can't easily do it without using Mandrill, you can pretend Mandrill's inbound features don't even exist.

If all you need is plain old incoming mail, just configure an MX record like usual.

Even if you need to use Mandrill's inbound features, that's best done on a subdomain. To quote [the docs](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/21699367-Inbound-Email-Processing-Overview):

> All email sent to this domain will be sent to Mandrill *instead of*
>   traditional email inboxes, so it's a good idea to use a subdomain,
>   like "inbound.yourdomain.com" that doesn't already exist.

Comment: The use of inbound.yourdomain.com was the missing piece of the puzzle for me. That way I can keep other email accounts functional