# How to receive emails with mailgun in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, digital-ocean, mailgun

I'm already using `mailgun` to send some data to an email (my gmail account). Now I want to receive emails using *@mydomain.com*

I saw this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14703446/how-to-receive-the-emails-using-mailgun-in-node-js) with 2 answers that seem useless.

I have already set a `Route` so I receive any msg send to `*@mydomain.com*` and to forward them to my personal email at gmail:

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGjsm.png

So I tried sending an email to my personal gmail but I'm not receiving any emails.

I have my website on a VPS in digital ocean in case that is important.

Answer (score 0):

So I just needed to add the MX records to DigitalOcean provided by mailgun here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5txnN.png

(link for more info: https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#verifying-your-domain)

Now I send data from another email to example@mydomain.com and then I recieve it.

When I try sending data to example@mydomain.com from the same domain that is set in the forward rule it does not work so try with a third party email it you have any problems.